# Define $T_1,T_2,T_3 : \mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two questions about linear algebra. Maybe if someone could help me with the first one I could try the second one and see how it goes.

Define $T_1,T_2,T_3: \mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ by

$$ T_1  
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x
\\y 
\\z
\end{bmatrix}\right) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
y
\\z 
\\x
\end{bmatrix}, $$ 
$$ T_2 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x
\\y  
\\z
\end{bmatrix}\right)= 
\begin{bmatrix}
x-y  
\\y-z  
\\z-x
\end{bmatrix},$$

$$ T_3  
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x
\\y 
\\z
\end{bmatrix}\right) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-x
\\y 
\\-z
\end{bmatrix}.$$

First I need to find $$ T_1T_2 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x
\\y  
\\z
\end{bmatrix}\right)$$ and then I can try and find by myself $$T_2T_3\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x
\\y  
\\z
\end{bmatrix}\right).$$

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I am not sure how to begin that's where I wanted some guidance with number 1 so I could try number 2

Comment: would I multiply t1 by t2?

Comment: Remember that $T_1\circ T_2(v) = T_1 ( T_2(v))$, then remember that when they refer to $x,y,z$ here they are referring to the first entry, the second entry, and the third entry respectively of whatever the input is *regardless of what the input actually looks like*.

Comment: @ JMoravitz How do I begin then?

Comment: Let us look at a smaller example first.  This is, in essence, a question about how to do composition of functions.  If $f(x)=3x^2$ then $f(z)=3z^2$ and $f(52y) = 3(52y)^2$.  By applying $f$ to the input, whatever the input looked like, you plug that input in wherever you see the $x$ in the original definition.  This is even if the input is written with $x$'s as well., so $f(52x)=3(52x)^2$.  The same logic applies here with your linear transformations except that you have to keep track of three inputs (i.e. a vector) instead of just one and there are three outputs (i.e. also a vector).

Comment: @ JMoravitz thanks for your explanation that helped me out along with Astyx's help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still seem confused, so let me rewrite this a bit.  Maybe colors will help.

$T_2\left(\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\ z\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}x-y\\y-z\\z-x\end{bmatrix}$ is how it was originally written.

Lets give it colors and shapes as inputs instead...

$T_2\left(\begin{bmatrix} \color{red}{\bullet}\\ \color{orange}{\clubsuit}\\ \color{green}{\Delta}\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}\color{red}{\bullet}-\color{orange}{\clubsuit}\\\color{orange}{\clubsuit}-\color{green}{\Delta}\\\color{green}{\Delta}-\color{red}{\bullet}\end{bmatrix}$

So, if we want to apply $T_2$ to some input vector, the resulting first coordinate is the input's first coordinate minus the input's second coordinate.  The resulting second coordinate is the input's second coordinate minus the input's third coordinate, etc...

Let us see a few examples:

$T_2\left(\begin{bmatrix} \color{red}{5}\\ \color{orange}{2}\\ \color{green}{a}\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}\color{red}{5}-\color{orange}{2}\\\color{orange}{2}-\color{green}{a}\\\color{green}{a}-\color{red}{5}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}5-2\\2-a\\a-5\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3\\2-a\\a-5\end{bmatrix}$

$T_2\left(\begin{bmatrix} \color{red}{52x^2}\\ \color{orange}{z}\\ \color{green}{5+x}\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}\color{red}{52x^2}-\color{orange}{z}\\\color{orange}{z}-(\color{green}{5+x})\\(\color{green}{5+x})-\color{red}{52x^2}\end{bmatrix}$

So... we want to find $T_2\left[T_3\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\right)\right]$

What is $T_3\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\right)$.  Once we have completed having applied $T_3$ to the original input we get an output and this output will be used as our *new* input for $T_2$.  If we color code this new input like above, what is the red part?  What is the orange part?  The final result's first entry will be the red part minus the orange part, what is that?

> $T_3\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}-x\\y\\-z\end{bmatrix}$ so we do $T_2\left(\begin{bmatrix}(-x)~~~~~\text{this is red}\\y~~~~~\text{this is orange}\\(-z)~~~~~~\text{this is green}\end{bmatrix}\right)=\dots$

Comment: reading over that I finally understand what you are saying, thanks so much for your time you have explained everything quite clearly

Comment: I must say I'm impressed by this answer

Answer (score 0):

You have :

$$T_1\circ T_2\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x
\\y 
\\z
\end{bmatrix}\right) =
T_1\left( T_2\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x
\\y 
\\z
\end{bmatrix}\right)\right)
 =T_1\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x-y
\\y-z 
\\z-x
\end{bmatrix}\right)=
\begin{bmatrix}
y-z
\\z-x 
\\x-y
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: okay so you take $T_2$ and then whatever is in $T_1$ in the x position wherever you see a x you replace it with that, so in this case a y

Comment: @ Astyx so in this case for number 2 you should have:

$$T2\circ T_3\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x
\\y 
\\z
\end{bmatrix}\right) =
T_2\left( T_3\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x
\\y 
\\z
\end{bmatrix}\right)\right)
 =T_2\left(\begin{bmatrix}
-x
\\y
\\-z
\end{bmatrix}\right)=
\begin{bmatrix}
y-x
\\y-z 
\\x-z
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: @geohelp be careful.  Remember that $T_2$ acts like (first minus second, second minus third, third minus first).  Be mindful of your negative signs.  If the first is $(-x)$ and the second is $(y)$, what is the first minus the second?

Comment: @ JMoravitz yes I noticed and quickly edited not sure if you saw before you wrote

Comment: @ JMoravitz shouldn't -x = y - x? and y = y-z? and -z = x - z?

Comment: @geohelp We are working with the result of having already applied $T_3$., so when we apply $T_2$ to find the first coordinate in the *result* we take the first for the input of $T_2$ (in this case being $-x$) and subtract the second for the input of $T_2$ (in this case being $y$) getting $(-x)-y = -x-y$, not $y-x$.  Also, be careful how you phrase things., you used an $x$ on the left and on the right but you imply that you mean different things with each, (on the left probably meaning the first coordinate of the final result and on the right meaning the first coordinate of the original input)

Comment: I was getting confused and subbing x in for both x and y in the first entry, that's where I was messing up I believe

Comment: @ JMoravitz so it should be -x-y, y+ z, -z+x